# Why does my big string of bytes overwrite text at the top of my file?

Tags: php

Irrelevant context: running a php script to get a file transferred from one db to another, basically.

My code:

```
1  $urlVar = "http://www.website.com/api/file_service.php?action=download&companyID=1234&pass=4321&videoID=123456";
2  $file = file_get_contents($urlVar);
3  if ($handle = fopen($urlVar, 'r')) {
4      $stream = stream_get_contents($handle, -1, 0);
5      fclose($handle);
6  }
7
8  $output = date("F j, Y, g:i:s a") . "\n\n";
9  $output .= $urlVar . "\n";
10 $output .= $file . "\n\n\n\n";
11 $output .= $stream . "\n";
12 file_put_contents('file.txt', $output . "\n");
```

Output (I've typed in the line numbers myself. They aren't actually in the file):

```
1     6e65 2037 2c20 3230 3138 2c20 323a 4a75
2     3831 3230 2663 6f6d 7061 6e79 5061 7373
3     3020 2d20 6874 7470 3a2f 2f77 7777 2e76
      ...
43129 0000 0000 0000 0000 002b 696c 7374 0000
43130 0001 0000 0000 4c61 7666 3532 2e39 332e
43131 300a 0a
```

Note: in the file, I don't see any line breaks. I assumed that putting 4 \n's would show up, but they don't. Is my file getting turned into solely hex??

Output if lines 10 and 11 are commented:

```
1 June 7, 2018, 1:56:00 pm
2 
3 http://www.website.com/api/file_service.php?action=download&companyID=1234&pass=4321&videoID=123456
```

Comment: It is `"\n"` not `'\n'`

Comment: That was me testing. I'll change it back in the question. Either way, I don't see the line breaks in the output file.

Comment: Looks like the file might be a binary? What sort of file are you trying to download?

Comment: Video file. It's a .mp4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to download the remote output with `file_get_contents` and then store it in a local file?
Then it's simple

```
$urlVar = "http://www.website.com/api/file_service.php?action=download&companyID=1234&pass=4321&videoID=123456";
$file = file_get_contents($urlVar);
//check not FALSE
if ($file) {
    $handle = fopen('localfile.txt', 'w');
    //if you append the date before you will break the file
    //in the case it's not a normal text file you will need when reading
    //a code that skips the first line
    fwrite($handle, date("F j, Y, g:i:s a")."\n\n");
    //better to avoid it and just put the timestamp in db or in filename------
    fwrite($handle, $file);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

If file_get_contents fails then it's php.ini fault, change `allow_url_fopen` to `On`

Comment: I get what you're saying. I was just testing. I will not actually be modifying the file to have a timestamp at the top of it. Although all of that is true, I tried opening a handle with 'w' onto the local file, and then calling fwrite twice. I get the same output. Only bytes appearing.

Comment: Perfect, I also suggest to use `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents`, also if it's a bit more complicated is only because is very complete of every option possible. Edit: what do you mean with "only bytes appearing"? Try to visit the url manually with your browser and see if the content is what you except

Comment: When I visit the site manually, the content is as expected. The content is a downloadable video file. I was initially confused why when trying to combine the return string from file_get_contents with an already created string of stuff (date and url), it only showed the stream of bytes that file_get_contents returned. As you suggest, I may end up using cURL.

Comment: Reading your example output with an Hex editor it shows up that `4C 61 76 66 35 32` is `Lavf52` which is a video codec magic flag, so I think that your video is just there